# Проблема с адаптацией сайта

Tags: html, css, веб-сайт

Нужно адаптировать сайт под разные разрешения. Перепробовал много способов. Никак не выходит
Вот код. Подскажите как это нормально сделать на уже готовом сайте
https://pastebin.com/VrSPRCeU
https://pastebin.com/fwpWSc7W

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: При условии того, что видно в коде, могу посоветовать только обратиться на фриланс, для написания нормального кода и с адаптивом. Если же хотите самостоятельно разобраться и есть время - то изучайте HTML и CSS, адаптив и прочее.

Comment: А возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при заходе на сайт у человека открывался другой html css специально сделанный для мобильных устройств?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Адаптив - значит правильное отображение на разных устройствах, у Вас должен быть дизайн под разные устройства.

Представим, что у Вас есть дизайн, как понять когда какие стили задавать?

Для этого есть крутая штука `media` запросы. Пишем в нашем файле `.css` :

```css
@media(min-width:768px){
  /* Работает только больше 768px */
  .style{
    color: #fff;
  }
}

@media(max-width:768px){
  /* Работает только меньше 768px */
  .style{
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

Здесь Вы можете прописывать разные стили под разные устройства (по ширине устройств). Подробнее: [media запросы в css](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

`уже готовом сайте` большинство придется переделать. Нет волшебной кнопки, которая всё сделает)

Также добавьте в вашем `html` в теге `<head>`:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
Подробнее: [Viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Viewport)

Comment: спасибо, считаю что помогли